# variable inside for loop disappears in shell script

Tags: shell, loops, variables, unix

I am using result variable in if loop which is inside for loop. When I print result at the end of the file, I get "SERVER_STATUS:error", but I want to get "SERVER_STATUS:success". What should I change to get respected output?

```
result="SERVER_STATUS:error"
  for i in $(seq 1 10)
  do
   if [ "$i" = 4 ]; then
    result="SERVER_STATUS:success"
    echo $result
    break
   fi
  done


echo "$result"
```

Note: I am using shell script.

Update1 :-

If I use export with variable, its works as I want. Is there any problem in it?

```
 result="SERVER_STATUS:error"
      for i in $(seq 1 10)
      do
       if [ "$i" = 4 ]; then
        export result="SERVER_STATUS:success"
        echo $result
        break
       fi
      done


    echo "$result"
```

Comment: Cannot duplicate.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Kindly refer my update and tell your suggestion

Comment: Both return `SERVER_STATUS:success` twice, as expected.

Comment: What shell you are using? Try `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of your script.

Comment: @karan What shell you use, your first script works for me. I get the result that you want. I use bash shell.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT I am not using bash in first script.

Comment: @karan  Hi, which shell do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line:

```
if [ "$i" = 4 ]; then

with
if [ "$i" = "4" ]; then

or
if [ $i -eq 4 ]; then
```